# SNMP - простыми словами

Tags: snmp

Объясните что такое SNMP и для чего он нужен. Мало информации и практически ничего не понятно.

Comment: http://www.laes.ru/list/pve/SNMP/tcp25.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В двух словах:

1. SNMP - сетевой протокол для управления устройствами, способными общаться по IP протоколу;
2. ПО, реализующее этот протокол, состоит из двух частей: клиента и менеджера:
3. Клиент работает на управляемой железяке;
4. Менеджер работает на хосте сисадмина;
5. Менеджер посылает клиенту *запросы* на чтение/запись управляющих переменных (переменная соответствует, как правило, управляющему регистру железяки);
6. Клиент посылает менеджеру *трапы* о случившихся событиях.

   В принципе - всё. НО !!! Создатели SNMP попытались объять необъятное:

   - Передавать/принимать **любые** типы данных
   - Управлять **любыми** типами устройств.

В результате, для кодирования данных используется целая иерархия стандартов:

1. BER
2. ASN.1
3. TLV в самом SNMP

Для работы с различными устройствами была придумана такая монструозная система, которая называется MIB - база данных управления. Это и в самом деле БД, только не реляционная, а иерархическая. И в ней содержатся описания всех управляющих регистров всех сетевых устройств, разработанных всеми фирмами мира за все времена.... У-ф-ф-ф...  Естественно, что тащить её целиком невозможно в принципе.

Поэтому, каждый агент на всех устройствах состоит из двух частей:

- Базовая часть, работающая с частью MIB, общей для всех устройств;
- Конкретная часть, называемая *субагентом*, работающая только с той частью MIB, которая используется на этой конкретной железяке.

Как правило, тулзы для написания агентов содержат базовую часть агента в готовом виде и библиотеку для написания субагентов.

С менеджерами проще, так как они не взаимодействуют  с реальным железом и представляют из себя обычный IP/UDP клиент, который формирует и отправляет пакеты SNMP на порт 161 и слушает порт 162 (это уже больше похоже на UDP сервер).

Лично моё мнение (с которым многие не согласятся) такое: ничего более монструозного, нелепого и чудовищного по неэффективности за всю историю программирования создано не было.

Проблема в том, что никакой альтернативы нет...